# No alert popping up, although variable is defined, and syntax LOOKS correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var Bold="Yes!  There is bold in the text above!!";
  var NoBold="No... There isn't any bolded text in the paragraph above..";
  var BoldButton='<input class="BoldButton" type="button" value="Bold?" id="WelcomeBoldButton">';

  $(BoldButton).insertAfter('#intro');
  $(BoldButton).insertAfter('#LatestNews');

  $(BoldButton).click(function(){
    if($(this).prev().is(':has(b, strong)')){
      alert(Bold);
      } else {
        alert(NoBold);
      }
});

});
```

For some reason, the alert won't pop up upon clicking the instances of the variables even though the buttons are showing up..

UPDATE:

Here is a working version of the code.  I apologize but I'm still very new to JS and jQuery but I don't really understand why this version is working..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var Bold="Yes, some of this text is Bolded!";
  var NoBold="No, none of this text is Bolded..";
  var BoldButton='<input class="BoldButton" type="button" value="Bold?">';
  var MakeMeMoreBoldButton='<input class="MakeMeMoreBoldButton" type="button" value="MakeMe More Bold!">';
  var MakeMeBoldButton='<input class="MakeMeBoldButton" type="button" value="Make Me       Bold!">';

  $(BoldButton).insertAfter('#disclaimer');
  $(BoldButton).appendTo('#navigation');
  $(BoldButton).insertAfter('#intro');

  $('.BoldButton').click(function(){
  if($(this).prev().is(':has(b, strong)')){
  alert(Bold);
  $(this).prev().addClass('BoldText');
  $(MakeMeMoreBoldButton).insertAfter(this).prev();
  $('.MakeMeMoreBoldButton').click(function(){
    $('.BoldText').css('font-weight', 'bold');
  });
  }  
else{
  alert(NoBold);
  $(this).prev().addClass('MakeMeBold');
  $(MakeMeBoldButton).insertAfter(this).prev();
  $('.MakeMeBoldButton').click(function(){
    $('.MakeMeBold').css('font-weight', 'bold');
  });
  }
  });
  });
```

Comment: Hey @BOSS could you take a minute to read the question formatting guide?  When you post code, you need to indent it by 4 or more spaces or else it ends up looking messed up (or sometimes not visible at all).

Comment: Actually, I tried that, and for some reason it didn't work, but let me try again.

Comment: Well somebody fixed it for you at some point - also note that it  has to be spaces, not tabs.

Comment: OK, sorry, I wasn't trying to do that.

Comment: There's an issue with your code. You're creating 2 `BoldButton` and appending them. The trouble is that they String used to create them has an ID, which means that you'll have 2 elements with the same ID. This isn't good. I'll leave an answer in a minute that assigns unique IDs and gives them `click` handlers before they are inserted.

Comment: BOSS - If you select your code and click the *Code Sample* button at the top of the edit area (looks like 101010), it will indent for you. You can also use the `CTRL + k` shortcut to indent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not going to work, as you've demonstrated by empirical testing. What you're doing is creating some DOM content and then copying it a couple times into the document. You need to set up your "click" handlers on the *real* DOM nodes that are actually in the document.

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's the correct answer!  The OP is adding the click handler to a jQuery wrapper created from a HTML string, not the elements that have been inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks @Andy E ~~sniff~~~ my poor answer :(

Comment: How do I set up the click handlers on the real DOM nodes that are actually in the document?

Comment: +1 Since I can't stand it when people down-vote without giving reason. They should read the faq.

Comment: @BOSS you could do what @Stefan suggested, or you could just do `$('button.BoldButton').click(function() { ... })` after you do the "insertAfter" calls.

Answer (score 1):

Move the event handler before the insertions. A better way to do this, however, is this:

```
  $('.BoldButton').live('click',function{

     if($(this).prev().is(':has(b, strong)')){
       alert(Bold);
     } else {
       alert(NoBold);
     }
 });
```

Comment: If the event handler is set up (with .live() like that) in that function, then those variables will be in scope.

Comment: OK, I sort of get it, but why is it not in the scope yet?  I have it placed first, if that matters.

Also, what does .live really do?  The jQuery API just kind of confused me on this one.. :)

Comment: The "live" routine will put an event handler on the `<body>` tag. That handler will be called by any "click" event on the page. When the handler gets an event, it checks to see if it's actual target element matches the selector used to set it up: in this case, ".BoldButton".  If it does match, then that handler will call *your* event handler, which will then work pretty much like it would if it had been attached with just "click" (not exactly but close enough for most purposes).

Comment: You clearly don't understand the purpose of live, then. The point is that this might not be the only place .BoldButton elements get created, and as such this is the **preferred way to add event handlers to dynamically created DOM elements**.

Comment: Stefan - I also don't understand why you don't think those variables are in scope. You could actually place your `.live()` *before* the variable declarations inside `.ready()` and it would work.

Comment: @Patrick: Righto. I was thinking of C-like variable binding, in which case Bold and NoBold would be out of scope. Ack.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attatching the click event before inserting the buttons into the DOM.